# Behavior of "+=" operator in python

Tags: python

Why does the output for following code differs in python,

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]  
>>> B = A  
>>> B += [4]  
>>> print A,B  
Output: A = [1,2,3,4] , B = [1,2,3,4]
```

But if we replace `B += [4]` to `B = B + [4]` the output changes to:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3] , B = [1,2,3,4]
```

Please explain.

Comment: sorry for reposting it, wasn't able to find it while searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` is augmented addition; for mutable types it alters the object *in place*.

You would get the same effect if you did:

```
B.extend([4])
```

Assigning `B` to `A` does not create a copy, so `B` and `A` refer to the same object, and any changes to that object are visible through both references.

When, however you use `B = B + [4]` you create a *new* list object, and rebind `B` to that new object. Because a new list object is created, the original list object (previously referenced by `B` and still referenced by `A`) is unaffected.

In effect, by using straight concatenation, you created a shallow copy of the original list object.